# Runtime.ImportModuleError Error: Cannot find module 'axios/lib/utils' Serverless

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless

I am using the Serverless framework. Backend as node.js. I have several microservices and all others are working fine, but now I have created now microservice where I have not used `Axios` but still, it is throwing error in the console.
One more issue is that in my local system it works perfectly, but as I push the same into the server then it starts creating issues.
[image: project directory image]

This is the sample code which is throwing error

```
    const { IamAuthenticator } = require('ibm-watson/auth');
    const NaturalLanguageUnderstandingV1 = require('ibm-watson/natural-language-understanding/v1');

    async function textAnalyse(req, res) {
      const naturalLanguageUnderstanding = new NaturalLanguageUnderstandingV1({
      version: '2019-07-12',
      authenticator: new IamAuthenticator({
        apikey: 'API KEY'
      }),
    url: 'https://URL/natural-language-understanding/api'
    });

    const analyzeParams = {
       'text': HtmlToText.fromString('Test text here'),
       'features': {
         'entities': {
           'sentiment': true,
           'limit': 100
          }
        }
    };

    const analysis = await naturalLanguageUnderstanding.analyze(analyzeParams);

    // prepare the response object
    res.send({ analysis: analysis });
  }
```

Error in AWS Cloud watch
`{
    "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
    "errorMessage": "Error: Cannot find module 'axios/lib/utils'",
    "stack": [
        "Runtime.ImportModuleError: Error: Cannot find module 'axios/lib/utils'",
        "    at _loadUserApp (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:100:13)",
        "    at Object.module.exports.load (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:140:17)",
        "    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/index.js:45:30)",
        "    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)",
        "    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)",
        "    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)",
        "    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)",
        "    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)",
        "    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)",
        "    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)",
        "    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:623:3)"
    ]
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the fixes for this.
when we call third-party API from our Lambda it requires the Axios to be implemented internally. So you need to create a folder that will have a package.json file with the dependency

```
"dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19.2"
  }
```

Then add the layer in the functions from AWS UI, left side menu
[image: Steps to Add layer]

Then add the layer to your function
[image: Added layer to the function]

Now, by doing the above activity the issue will be resolved and Axios dependency is added successfully individually to the microservice.

Comment: Thanks for this. I have tried to this. I actually found this link https://medium.com/@anjanava.biswas/nodejs-runtime-environment-with-aws-lambda-layers-f3914613e20e but I am still getting the error

` "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
  "errorMessage": "Error: Cannot find module 'axios'\nRequire stack:\n- /var/task/index.js\n- /var/runtime/UserFunction.js\n- /var/runtime/index.js",
  "trace": [
    "Runtime.ImportModuleError: Error: Cannot find module 'axios'",`

Any ideas pls?

Answer (score 0):

Also, what you name the folders matters before zipping. Review these AWS docs for folder naming so you can import the library like you would in any other project.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html